# Gantt view or hierarchical grid

Tags: .net, winforms, view, grid, gantt-chart

Is there any any free Gantt view grid control or hierarchical grid view available in WinForms?

I require a grid that looks like an MS project task list, but it should not contain a right side calendar view as in MS project. My requirement is just to maintain hierarchical data with multiple columns.

Could you please suggest where can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a good answer?

It's a project with source code

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Gantt_Chart.aspx